# Nokogiri and xpath parsing an HTML table

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, html-table, nokogiri

I can set up parsing, and connect to a site but, when I run the script,
it returns an empty NodeSet:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'ap'

time = Time.new

url = <<-EOS
'http://www.events.psu.edu/cgi-bin/cal/webevent.cgi?cmd=listday&y=%d&m=%d&d=%d&cat=&sib=1&sort=m,e,t&ws=0&cf=list&set=1&swe=1&sa=1&de=1&tf=0&sb=1&stz=Default&cal=cal299' % [time.year, time.month, time.day]
EOS

page = Nokogiri::HTML(url)

rows =  page.xpath('/html/body/p/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/p/table/tbody/tr[2]')
details = rows.collect do |row|
detail = {}
[
 [:time, 'td[3]/p/text()'],
 [:name, 'td[4]/div/a/b/font/text()'],
 [:location, 'td[4]/div[2]/text()'],
 [:details, 'td[4]/div[4]/text()'],
].collect do |name, xpath|

detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
end
detail
end
ap details
```

The returned value is `"[]"`.

This is the HTML file before the table `/html/body/p/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/p`:

```
<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=3 WIDTH="100%">

<!--Begin Event-->
<TR>
  <TD WIDTH="2%">
    <P></P>
  </TD>
  <TD WIDTH="10%">
    <P></P>
  </TD>
  <TD WIDTH="19%">

    <P></P>
  </TD>
  <TD WIDTH="60%">
    <P></P>
  </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<!--Icon Section-->
  <TD CLASS="listeventbg" VALIGN=top WIDTH="2%">
    <P CLASS="listeventicon">&nbsp;</P>

  </TD>
<!--Date Section-->
  <TD CLASS="listeventbg" VALIGN=top WIDTH="10%">
    <P CLASS="listeventdate">Mar 14</P>
  </TD>
<!--Time Section-->
  <TD CLASS="listeventbg" VALIGN=top WIDTH="19%">
    <P CLASS="listeventtime">8:30 a.m. - 4:30 p.m.<BR>
</P>

  </TD>
<!--Main Event Section-->
  <TD CLASS="listeventbg" VALIGN=top WIDTH="60%">
<div class=listeventtitlelarge><A HREF="http://www.pennstatehershey.org/web/diabetesresearch/home">
<B><font color="#0000CC">2011 Diabetes and Obesity Research Spring Summit</FONT></B></A>
</div>
<div class=listeventtitle><B>Calendar:</B> HHD Seminars<BR>
<B>Posted by:</B> <A HREF="mailto:luk10%40psu.edu">Lauren Kipp</A><BR><B>Location:</B> The Nittany Lion Inn<BR>

</div>
<DIV CLASS="listeventspacer"> </DIV>
<DIV CLASS="listeventdetails">
<B>Details:</B><BR>Registration and Abstract Deadline: February 15, 2011<BR>        <BR>Registration: Please follow the link for more details and access to on line registration. Space is limited, so please register early to ensure your seat at the conference.<BR><BR>The Keynote Speaker for this year’s event is <b>Dr. Robert Sherwin, from the Yale School of Medicine.</b>  Dr. Sherwin is known for his research in the effect of insulin on brain function and immune mechanisms leading to type 1 diabetes.  The topic of his presentation is <i>Pathophysiological Mechanisms in Diabetes, from Laboratory to Bedside.</i><BR><BR>A welcome to the University Park campus will be offered by <b>Eugene Marsh, MD</b>, Senior Associate Dean for the Penn State College of Medicine Regional Medical Campus and Associate Director of the Penn State Hershey Medical Group in State College<BR><BR>Abstract Submission<BR>Please follow the link for formatting details and to register your intent to submit an abstract using the on-line form.<BR>    <BR>You will receive a confirmation immediately upon submission of your on-line form. Subsequently, the final formatted abstract must be sent directly to Continuing Ed by email attachment (see website instructions). Within 48 hours of sending your abstract in final format, you will receive an email confirmation from ContinuingEd@hmc.psu.edu indicating that both your form & the abstract attachment have been received.<BR><BR><i>All abstracts will be considered for poster presentations. A subset of these abstracts will be selected and invited for brief oral presentations during the “Poster Headlines” plenary sessions. To be considered for an oral presentation, please be sure to meet the submission deadline for submission of your final abstract. Prizes will be awarded for the top three posters from by post-doc/fellow/student presenters.</i>

</div>
</TD>
<!--EndEvent-->
......Followed by more of the same format
```

I am trying to get the name of the event, the time, location and the description of the event.

Comment: There is no `TBODY` element in your not well formed input sample. **FAQ: browsers add mandatory (X)HTML elements to DOM** (like `head` or `tbody`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simplified version of how I'd go about it.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'ap'

time = Time.new

url = 'http://www.events.psu.edu/cgi-bin/cal/webevent.cgi?cmd=listday&y=%d&m=%d&d=%d&cat=&sib=1&sort=m,e,t&ws=0&cf=list&set=1&swe=1&sa=1&de=1&tf=0&sb=1&stz=Default&cal=cal299' % [time.year, time.month, time.day]

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

details = page.search('//tr/td[@class="listeventbg"]/..').map do |row|
  time     = row.at( 'p.listeventtime'         ).text.strip rescue ''
  name     = row.at( 'div.listeventtitlelarge' ).text.strip rescue ''
  location = row.at( 'div.listeventtitle'      ).text.strip rescue ''
  details  = row.at( 'div.listeventdetails'    ).text.strip rescue ''

  {
    :time     => time,
    :name     => name,
    :location => location,
    :details  => details
  }
end

ap details
```

Rather than rely on long XPath accessors, often it's easier to break down the search. This loops over the rows, then, for each row, does a simple lookup for the cells.

Normally I wouldn't use `rescue ''` but for quick and dirty it's OK. For production I'd set up real exception handling.

Your sample code required Mechanize, but didn't use it, so I removed it for this example. It didn't include a way to have Nokogiri retrieve the HTML, so I added Open-URI.

Nokogiri allows use of CSS and XPath accessors. A lot of times CSS will result in a simpler search. XPath has more power, but that can come at the price of complexity. `/tr/td[@class="listeventbg"]/..` looks for rows with the embedded cells, then steps back to the row level.

Comment: What is `ap`? Is it some pretty-print gem? Coundn't find it in the internets.

Comment: ap is a gem also known as awesome_print, its similar to pretty print but has a more colorful output in the terminal. This was a great help thank you for the tip! this was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath instead of the CSS accessor like so:

```
//div[@class='listeventtitlelarge']
```

but, remember, this is a full text match so foobar will also be caught. In any case, you can modify it with a few simple regex functions or just don't use too similar class names. Or, you could also go with "[XPATH CSS CLASS MATCHING](http://pivotallabs.com/users/alex/blog/articles/427-xpath-css-class-matching)" from the pivotall guys.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are parsing through the structure instead of using the classes that are given in the document. I would use the CSS classes the document creator put in, like this:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(url)
eventdate = page.at_css("p.listeventdate").content
eventtime = page.at_css("p.listeventtime").content
details =   page.at_css("div.listeventdetails").content
```

If you are doing this on a larger document, where multiple results will be returned, then use `css` and iterate through the results instead of `at_css`. The latter only finds one instance of the tag and class.

It looks like everything you want has a selector that makes more sense than the direct path. It also makes it more resilient to change because, if they change the structure and keep the same classes, then your parsing still works.